# Renaming specific character python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, file-rename, shutil

I am trying to write a code to use rename the files. Basically I want to add "*fluid_mask*",

This is what I wrote so far

```
import os
import shutil

from tqdm import tqdm

src= r"C:\Users\cetinh\Desktop\New folder (7)"
dest = r"C:\Users\cetinh\Desktop\New folder (8)"

for filename in tqdm(os.listdir(src), position=0, leave=True, dynamic_ncols=True, desc="Total"):
        file_path = os.path.join(src, filename)
        a = os.path.join(src, filename.replace(filename[-9], "_fluid_mask_"))
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(a))) ==1:
            pass
            tqdm.write("Skipping " + filename)
        else:
            os.rename(file_path, a)
            shutil.move(a, dest)
            tqdm.write("Copying " + filename + "-----> " + os.path.basename(a))
```

this is what I get

```
Copying 840624002_OS_V9_20170310_0102.png -----> 840624002_fluid_mask_OS_fluid_mask_V9_fluid_mask_20170310_fluid_mask_0102.png
```

So as far as I understand it just replace "_" with "*fluid_mask*" but I need only replace the last underscore in the filename.

Can anyone give me an idea about how can solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Use a regular expression with `re.sub()` instead of `str.replace()`

Comment: Or split the filename with `str.split('_')`, insert `fluid_mask` before the last element, then join it back together.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` replaces *all* the substring occurrences in the string. What you want is probably something like

```py
i = filename.rfind('_') #find the last underscore
filename = filename[:i] + "_fluid_mask_" + filename[i+1:]
```